# When should a faculty candidate notify schools about a competing offer?

Tags: job-search, tenure-track, negotiation

If a candidate has been notified that she is going to receive an offer from another school, at what point should she notify other schools at which she has interviewed? In particular, if it's known that the other school is on a much slower trajectory to make a decision—say, six weeks or more—what should a candidate do, either to determine if other offers will be forthcoming, or to expedite the process?

Comment: Are you asking for a pragmatic perspective, an ethical perspective, or both?

Comment: Mainly pragmatic. (See slight revision to question.)

Comment: This is somewhat unclear. What should a candidate do to reach what goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it depends on the deadline the offering school gave you. If it's after you expect to hear from the other schools, maybe waiting will be OK. If it's before, then you may have to light a fire under the slower schools. Also, there's a big difference between being "notified that she is going to receive an offer from" the first school and actually receiving it. I wouldn't do anything until you have the first offer in hand (or email).

Comment: You mean you'd wait for the official offer?  Why?